# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, and nothing is working

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

### I've been sitting and looking at this code for a few hours and I don't understand where I went wrong, why it doesn't work.

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I saw that this is a topic that is discussed alot but for some reason none of the examples I have seen has helped me. I'm pretty sure it's all right with the parentheses.

**Here is the code:**

```
CREATE TABLE ADT_FILIALA_AGENTIE (
  id_f  NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
  name  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  telephone  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  adress  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  nr_an  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  id_a  int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_f),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_a) REFERENCES ADT_AGENTIE_PRINCIPALA(id_a) 
);
```

Comment: If you don't see where it goes wrong in a statement like this: start by removing lines and see at what point it starts working. That gives you a clue as to where the error is exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify precision for the `int` data type in Oracle. You are using it for column `id_a`. `int` is shorthand for `number(38,0)`.

To get the desired effect, replace that with `number(11,0)` - which means precision of 11 digits, of which zero decimal places.

Other than that, you would be well advised, in Oracle, to use `varchar2(n)` rather than `varchar(n)`. For a very long time Oracle has warned us that in future releases `varchar` may be used for something else (even though that hasn't happened and is unlikely to happen).

To explain the error message: Right after the parser reads `id_a int` it expects (optional space and) a comma, or a constraint, etc. What it does not expect (since it makes no sense in that position) is an opening parenthesis, as you have in `(11)`. The error handling is written to assume that at that point the `create table` statement should have ended - with a closing parenthesis. It doesn't find it, so it complains about that.

That's why you saw so many unrelated mentions of "missing right parenthesis" errors - they are often thrown by the parser when it finds something unexpected in a statement. The parser doesn't know what the real error is - it just sees something that doesn't make sense somewhere, and if at that point a closing parenthesis would have ended a valid statement, it throws that error.

Comment: Somewhat confusingly you *can* specify precision for INT in PL/SQL where it is actually defined as a subtype of NUMBER rather than a shorthand/alias/whatever is happening above.

Comment: It worked !! Thank you very much for explanation <3

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify precision for the int data type in Oracle. You are using it for column id_a int.

```
CREATE TABLE ADT_FILIALA_AGENTIE ( id_f  NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE,
name  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
telephone  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
adress  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
nr_an  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
id_a  int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_f),
FOREIGN KEY(id_a) REFERENCES ADT_AGENTIE_PRINCIPALA(id_a) );
```